# How to add Calendar, Date-Picker?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I need to add a Calendar Date Picker in Excel 2013.

I found that the MonthView and the DT Picker are no longer in the ActiveX menu and the links for a CAB file that supposedly contains these does not work. There are instruction documents, but they rely on a control that doesn't exist.

I have an Excel Addin that does what I want, but I want to do this with VBA rather than install the Addin on every machine that will use this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have registered the **mscomct2.ocx** control (**YOU WILL NEED TO REGISTER THIS FILE ON ALL COMPUTERS THAT WILL USE THIS WORKBOOK!**), you can either add one of below controls in the Worksheet or in a UserForm:

- Date and Time Picker (**DTPicker**), left/top of screenshots
- **MonthView**, right/bottom of screenshots

---

**WORKSHEET (ActiveX)**

1. In Developer tab, Controls group, click Insert, then bottom right
   button for More Controls.
    [image: Step1]
2. Scroll down and select **Microsoft Date and Time Picker Control 6.0 (SP6)**  or **Microsoft MonthView Control 6.0 (SP6)** then click OK.
   [image: Step2a] | [image: Step2b]
3. When you are out of Design Mode, clicking on the DTPicker control is like this, while the MonthView takes more space:
   [image: Step3a] | [image: Step3b]

---

**UserForm**

1. In the Toolbox for the UserForm selected, right click on empty space of the Controls tab, click Additional Controls
   [image: form step 1]
2. Scroll down and tick **Microsoft Date and Time Picker Control 6.0 (SP6)** or **Microsoft MonthView Control 6.0 (SP6)**:
   [image: form step 2a] | [image: form step 2b]
3. Now the controls are in your Controls tab to add on UserForms
   [image: form step 3]
4. Default size of the controls on UserForm:
   [image: form step 4]

---

In either way, you will need to implement the actions when you click on these controls.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, however the correct controls do not appear in my controls list.  There is a button that offers the option to "Register Custom".  When I navigate to the file, an error message indicates  "Cannot Register this control".  Now what?

Comment: @DonDesrosiers What version of mscomct2.ocx you got? Mine is 6.1.98.16

Answer (score 3):

Some users may not have the ability to use your DatePicker if their Excel is not formatted correctly.  I developed code that will create a dateGetter userform, get the user's date selection as a Global variable, and then delete the form.  It should be compatible with most systems, though I haven't tested it on others than my own.  Give it a shot.  If it works for you, give me a shout out....

August 2020:
Fixed a glitch - when selecting the original date that opened with the form the returning date was "00:00:00 AM" - I fixed that below to return the date showing in the label2 caption.

Also - MSForms reference is necessary for the dateGetter() subroutine to work properly or you get an error message when the forms objects are declared.  I've added another subroutine that can add that reference through VBA code, or in the VBA Editor goto "Tools --> References" and select the MSForms refwerence.  You must do this before attempting to run the dateGetter macro.

```
Public absDate As Date ' This Public Variable is necessary to pass selected date

Sub setGUIDReferences()
'   NOTE:  The dateGetter() sub will not work until the MSForms Reference is added to this workbook project
'   You can add the MSForms reference by running this sub first
'   Or go to Tools --> References and select the MSForms reference there
'   included below are several other common references you can use for other projects just uncomment them to add
'   *************************************************************************************************************

    On Error Resume Next
    'ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{000204EF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", 0, 0    '       Visual Basic For Applications
    'ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", 0, 0    '       Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library
    'ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", 0, 0    '       OLE Automation
    'ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{2DF8D04C-5BFA-101B-BDE5-00AA0044DE52}", 0, 0    '       Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{0D452EE1-E08F-101A-852E-02608C4D0BB4}", 0, 0    '       Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
    'ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{3050F1C5-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B}", 0, 0    '       Microsoft HTML Object Library
    'ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{EAB22AC0-30C1-11CF-A7EB-0000C05BAE0B}", 0, 0    '       Microsoft Internet Controls
    'ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{420B2830-E718-11CF-893D-00A0C9054228}", 0, 0    '       Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    'ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{86CF1D34-0C5F-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}", 0, 0    '       Microsoft Windows Common Controls-2 6.0 (SP6)
    'ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{4AFFC9A0-5F99-101B-AF4E-00AA003F0F07}", 0, 0    '       Microsoft Access 16.0 Object Library
    'ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{0002E157-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", 0, 0    '       Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3
    'ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{F5078F18-C551-11D3-89B9-0000F81FE221}", 0, 0    '       Microsoft MSXML2 for XML Scraping
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub dateGetter()
'   This creates dategetter userform for those without access to date picker
'   Bug Fixed: Aug 2020, Selecting Original Date was resulting in 12:00:00 AM

'*********
'   Note: MSForms Reference in Tools menu must be added to workbook first before this calendar script will work
'   You can add several commonly used references by running the "setGUIDReferences()" subroutine above.
'   Or go to Tools --> References and select the MSForms reference there
'*********

Dim myForm As Object, calendarForm As Object, newLabel As MSForms.Label, newSpinner As MSForms.SpinButton
Dim NewFrame As MSForms.Frame
Dim NewButton As MSForms.CommandButton, newButton2 As MSForms.CommandButton
Dim NewListBox As MSForms.ListBox
Dim smallDayArray
Dim xDiff As Long
Dim smallTextArray
Dim startDate As Date
Dim endDate As Date
    
    Set myForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)
    
    'Create the User Form
    With myForm
        .Properties("Caption") = "Select Date Range"
        .Properties("Width") = 247.5
        .Properties("Height") = 350
    End With
    
    'create button
    Set NewButton = myForm.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.commandbutton.1")
    With NewButton
        .Name = "CommandButton1"
        .Top = 288
        .Left = 138
        .Width = 42
        .Height = 24
        .Font.Size = 10
        .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
        .Caption = "Cancel"
    End With
    
    'create button
    Set NewButton = myForm.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.commandbutton.1")
    With NewButton
        .Name = "CommandButton2"
        .Top = 288
        .Left = 186
        .Width = 42
        .Height = 24
        .Font.Size = 10
        .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
        .Caption = "Select"
    End With
    
    
    'create frame
    Set NewFrame = myForm.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.frame.1")
    With NewFrame
        .Name = "Frame1"
        .Top = 54
        .Left = 24
        .Width = 192
        .Height = 180
        .Font.Size = 9
        .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    End With
    
    'Create label1
    Set newLabel = myForm.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
    With newLabel
        .Name = "Label1"
        .Top = 30
        .Left = 30
        .Width = 102
        .Height = 18
        .Font.Size = 12
        .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
        .ForeColor = RGB(128, 0, 0)
        .BackColor = RGB(256, 256, 256)
        .Caption = "November 2017"
    End With
    
    'Create label2
    Set newLabel = myForm.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
    With newLabel
        .Name = "Label2"
        .Top = 258
        .Left = 36
        .Width = 174
        .Height = 18
        .Font.Size = 12
        .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
        .ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Caption = "01/01/2017"
    End With
    
    
    'Create SpinButton1
    Set newSpinner = myForm.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.spinbutton.1")
    With newSpinner
        .Name = "SpinButton1"
        .Top = 24
        .Left = 144
        .Width = 12.75
        .Height = 25
    End With
    
    'Create Calendar Header Labels
    smallDayArray = Array("S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S")
    smallTextArray = Array("day1", "day2", "day3", "day4", "day5", "day6", "day7")
    xDiff = 18
    For i = LBound(smallDayArray) To UBound(smallDayArray)
        Set lbl = NewFrame.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
        With lbl
            .Name = smallTextArray(i)
            .Top = 6
            .Left = xDiff
            .Width = 12
            .Height = 18
            .Font.Size = 11
            .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
            .Caption = smallDayArray(i)
        End With
        xDiff = xDiff + 24
    Next i
    
    'Create Calendar boxes labels
    arrCounter = 1
    For j = 1 To 6
        xDiff = 12
        For k = 1 To 7
            Set lbl = NewFrame.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
            With lbl
                .Name = "lb_" & arrCounter
                Select Case j
                    Case 1
                        .Top = 24
                    Case 2
                        .Top = 48
                    Case 3
                        .Top = 72
                    Case 4
                        .Top = 96
                    Case 5
                        .Top = 120
                    Case 6
                        .Top = 144
                End Select
                .Left = xDiff
                .Width = 18
                .Height = 18
                .Font.Size = 11
                .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
                .Caption = " " & arrCounter
                .ForeColor = RGB(128, 0, 0)
                .BackColor = RGB(256, 256, 256)
            End With
            arrCounter = arrCounter + 1
            xDiff = xDiff + 24
        Next k
    Next j
    ''add code for form module
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 1, "Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 2, "absDate = 0"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 3, "Unload Me"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 4, "End Sub"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 5, ""
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 6, "Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinDown()"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 7, "Dim newDate1 As Date"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 8, "    newDate1 = DateValue(Left(Label1.Caption, Len(Label1.Caption) - 5) & " & Chr(34) & " 1, " & Chr(34) & " & Right(Label1.Caption, 4))"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 9, "    newDate1 = DateAdd(" & Chr(34) & "m" & Chr(34) & ", -1, newDate1)"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 10, "    Label1.Caption = MonthName(Month(newDate1)) & " & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & " & Year(newDate1)"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 11, "    Call clearBoxes"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 12, "   Run fillCal(newDate1)"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 13, "End Sub"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 14, "Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinUp()"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 15, "Dim newDate1 As Date"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 16, "    newDate1 = DateValue(Left(Label1.Caption, Len(Label1.Caption) - 5) & " & Chr(34) & " 1, " & Chr(34) & " & Right(Label1.Caption, 4))"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 17, "    newDate1 = DateAdd(" & Chr(34) & "m" & Chr(34) & ", 1, newDate1)"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 18, "    Label1.Caption = MonthName(Month(newDate1)) & " & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & " & Year(newDate1)"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 19, "    Call clearBoxes"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 20, "    Run fillCal(newDate1)"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 21, "End Sub"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 22, "Function dhDaysInMonth2(Optional dtmDate As Date = 0) As Integer"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 23, "    ' Return the number of days in the specified month.  Written by Chip Pierson"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 24, "    If dtmDate = 0 Then"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 25, "        ' Did the caller pass in a date? If not, use"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 26, "        ' the current date."
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 27, "        dtmDate = Date"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 28, "    End If"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 29, "    dhDaysInMonth2 = DateSerial(Year(dtmDate), _ "
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 30, "     Month(dtmDate) + 1, 1) - _ "
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 31, "     DateSerial(Year(dtmDate), Month(dtmDate), 1)"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 32, "End Function"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 33, "Public Sub UserForm_Activate()"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 34, "Dim currentDate As Date"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 35, ""
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 36, " For i = 1 To 42" & vbNewLine
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 37, "     txt = txt & " & Chr(34) & "Private Sub lb_" & Chr(34) & " & i & " & Chr(34) & "_Click()" & Chr(34) & " & vbNewLine" & vbNewLine
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 38, "     txt = txt & " & Chr(34) & "Dim newDate As Date" & Chr(34) & " & vbNewLine" & vbNewLine
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 39, " txt = txt & " & Chr(34) & "newDate = DateValue(Mid(Label1.Caption, 1, Len(Label1.Caption) - 5) &" & Chr(34) & " & Chr(34) &   " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & " & lb_" & " & i & " & Chr(34) & ".Caption & " & Chr(34) & " & Chr(34) & " & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & " & Chr(34) & " & Chr(34) & " & Right(Label1.Caption, 4))" & Chr(34) & " & vbNewLine" & vbNewLine
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 40, "     txt = txt & " & Chr(34) & "Label2.Caption = " & Chr(34) & " & Chr(34) & " & Chr(34) & "Date:  " & Chr(34) & " & Chr(34) & " & Chr(34) & " & newDate" & Chr(34) & " & vbNewLine" & vbNewLine
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 41, "txt = txt & " & Chr(34) & "End Sub" & Chr(34) & " & vbNewLine" & vbNewLine
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 42, "Next i" & vbNewLine
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 43, ""
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 44, "Label2.Caption =  Chr(34) &  Chr(34) "
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 45, "currentDate = DateValue(Month(Date) & " & Chr(34) & " 1" & Chr(34) & " & " & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & " & Year(Date))"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 46, "Run fillCal(currentDate)"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 47, "End Sub"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 48, "Function fillCal(startDate As Date)"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 49, "Dim currentDayOfMonth As Integer, i As Integer"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 50, "currentDayOfMonth = Day(Date)"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 51, "Dim startCal As Date, currentMonth as Integer"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 52, "Dim labelArray, sumVar3 As Long"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 53, "    Label2.Caption = " & Chr(34) & "" & Chr(34)
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 54, "    labelArray = Array(" & Chr(34) & "lb_1" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_2" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_3" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_4" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_5" _
                                                                & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_6" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_7" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_8" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_9" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) _
                                                                & "lb_10" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_11" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_12" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_13" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_14" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_15" & Chr(34) & ",  _"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 55, "                      " & Chr(34) & "lb_16" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_17" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_18" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_19" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_20" & Chr(34) & ", " & _
                                                                Chr(34) & "lb_21" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_22" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_23" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_24" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_25" & Chr(34) & ", " & _
                                                                Chr(34) & "lb_26" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_27" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_28" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_29" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_30" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_31" & Chr(34) & ", _"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 56, "                      " & Chr(34) & "lb_32" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_33" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_34" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_35" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_36" & Chr(34) & ", " & _
                                                                Chr(34) & "lb_37" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_38" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_39" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_40" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_41" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_42" & Chr(34) & ")"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 57, "    Label1 = MonthName(Month(startDate)) & " & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & " & Year(startDate)"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 58, "    sumVar3 = Weekday(startDate) - 1"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 59, "    "
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 60, "    For i = LBound(labelArray) To UBound(labelArray)"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 61, "            Me.Controls(labelArray(i)).Caption = " & Chr(34) & "" & Chr(34) & ""
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 62, "    Next i"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 63, "    "
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 64, "     For i = 1 To dhDaysInMonth2(startDate)"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 65, "         Me.Controls(labelArray(sumVar3)).Caption = i"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 66, "         If currentDayOfMonth = i And month(Date) = Month(StartDate)  And Year(Date) = Year(StartDate) Then"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 67, "             Me.Controls(labelArray(sumVar3)).BackColor = RGB(256, 0, 0)"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 68, "             Me.Controls(labelArray(sumVar3)).ForeColor = RGB(256, 256, 256)"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 69, "             Label2.Caption = " & Chr(34) & "Date:  " & Chr(34) & " & DateValue(Month(startDate) & " & Chr(34) & "/" & Chr(34) & " & i & " & Chr(34) & "/" & Chr(34) & " & Year(startDate))"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 70, "        End If"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 71, "        sumVar3 = sumVar3 + 1"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 72, "     Next i"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 73, "    "
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 74, "End Function"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 75, "Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 76, "    absDate = Replace(Me.Label2.Caption, " & Chr(34) & "Date:  " & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "):Unload Me"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 77, "End Sub"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 78, "Private Sub clearBoxes()"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 79, "Dim labelArray"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 80, "     Label2.Caption = " & Chr(34) & "" & Chr(34)
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 81, "    labelArray = Array(" & Chr(34) & "lb_1" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_2" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_3" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_4" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_5" _
                                                                & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_6" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_7" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_8" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_9" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) _
                                                                & "lb_10" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_11" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_12" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_13" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_14" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_15" & Chr(34) & ",  _"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 82, "                      " & Chr(34) & "lb_16" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_17" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_18" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_19" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_20" & Chr(34) & ", " & _
                                                                Chr(34) & "lb_21" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_22" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_23" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_24" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_25" & Chr(34) & ", " & _
                                                                Chr(34) & "lb_26" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_27" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_28" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_29" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_30" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_31" & Chr(34) & ", _"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 83, "                      " & Chr(34) & "lb_32" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_33" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_34" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_35" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_36" & Chr(34) & ", " & _
                                                                Chr(34) & "lb_37" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_38" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_39" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_40" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_41" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "lb_42" & Chr(34) & ")"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 84, "      For i = lbound(labelArray) to ubound(labelArray)"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 85, "         Me.Controls(labelArray(i)).BackColor = RGB(256, 256, 256)"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 86, "         Me.Controls(labelArray(i)).ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 87, "      next i"
    myForm.codemodule.insertlines 88, "End Sub"
    '   add click controls for date label boxes
    Dim myCounter As Long
    myCounter = 89
        For i = 1 To 42
            myForm.codemodule.insertlines myCounter, "Private Sub lb_" & i & "_Click()"
            myCounter = myCounter + 1
            myForm.codemodule.insertlines myCounter, "Dim newDate As Date"
            myCounter = myCounter + 1
            myForm.codemodule.insertlines myCounter, "Call clearBoxes"
            myCounter = myCounter + 1
            myForm.codemodule.insertlines myCounter, "absDate = DateValue(Left(Label1.Caption, Len(Label1.Caption) - 5) & " & Chr(34) & Chr(32) & Chr(34) & " & lb_" & i & ".Caption & " & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & Chr(38) & " Right(Label1.Caption, 4))"
            myCounter = myCounter + 1
            myForm.codemodule.insertlines myCounter, "Label2.Caption = " & Chr(34) & "Date:  " & Chr(34) & " & absDate" & vbNewLine
            myCounter = myCounter + 1
            myForm.codemodule.insertlines myCounter, "lb_" & i & ".backcolor = rgb(256,0,0)"
            myCounter = myCounter + 1
            myForm.codemodule.insertlines myCounter, "lb_" & i & ".forecolor = rgb(256,256,256)"
            myCounter = myCounter + 1
            myForm.codemodule.insertlines myCounter, "End Sub" & vbNewLine
            myCounter = myCounter + 1
    Next i
    'Add and show new userform
    absDate = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    Set calendarForm = VBA.UserForms.Add(myForm.Name)
    calendarForm.Show
    
    
    If absDate <> 0 Then
    '   Here is where you put your code to to use the selected date
    '   whhich is in the global variabole "absDate"
        startDate = absDate
        Debug.Print "Your First Date is " & startDate
    Else
        Beep
        MsgBox "You did not select a date"
        GoTo endItAll
    End If
    
    
     
endItAll:
    '   Uncomment the following line if you want to delete the form after using it
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove myForm
End Sub
Function dhDaysInMonth(Optional dtmDate As Date = 0) As Integer
    ' Return the number of days in the specified month.  Written by Chip Pierson
    If dtmDate = 0 Then
        ' Did the caller pass in a date? If not, use
        ' the current date.
        dtmDate = Date
    End If
    dhDaysInMonth2 = DateSerial(Year(dtmDate), _
     Month(dtmDate) + 1, 1) - _
     DateSerial(Year(dtmDate), Month(dtmDate), 1)
End Function
```

- 
- 
- 
- 

Comment: I love what you're doing in this code and that you're using Chip Pierson code.  I'm surprised it isn't rated higher but I guess no one realized what you're doing.

Comment: Chip Pierson is definitely a genius and has helped me tremendously with Date and date math.  Chip has a wonderful section on holidays and other work week functions.  Though I used some of his code here (and gave him credit), most of this code is my code geared toward portability of a hand made date picker.  At my work there are some stations that don't have all the references that my station has and the common EXCEL date picker will  just not work if a station doesn't have that GUID on it.  This one seems to work fine, knock on wood.

Comment: Also, if you remove the line "ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove myForm" then the form will not be removed.  Then you can use the form as any other type form with .show command.

Comment: Yep I saw that.  I used your code as a base and integrated it into a vacation tracking tool just to show case the power of VBA.  It's sad but it feels like corporate America is moving away from VBA which I love.  I'm now getting heavy push to use R which really isn't any better and doesn't have nearly as robust error handling.

Comment: My own problem is portability. Which is why I built this on-the-fly calendar userform that is universal. Everyone in my  company has MS Office.  Either different versions or some have the necessary references and others don't.  Those who don't have the references get nothing but errors, ergo deeming VBA a bunch of crap.  (And my ability as a programmer too.)  So that's why MS is leaning away from it I guess.  But that's the fault of the Excel system, not us.  Their error system should alert the user that a reference is missing and how to get it or make references portable in a separate module.

Comment: This is beautiful! This should be the top and the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have used mscomct2.ocx file to use a date picker in excel.
You need to register it and can then easily use the date picker

Comment: It could be my general ignorance of windows, but I am unable to register this file. It does not even appear to be in my system 32 folder. Even though I copy it there from downloads. I'm getting frustrated with something that should be very simple. I am using fusion on a mac, but I can't imagine that being the issue

Comment: @DonDesrosiers To register the **mscomct2.ocx**, first open command prompt As Administrator, then enter `regsvr32 /s "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mscomct2.ocx"` assuming that's the path you copied to.

Comment: ok.  thanks.  that worked.  But the core issue remains.  I don't see a calendar date picker among the activeX controls.  Assuming that you know what it is called, I will still need help setting this up.  Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the DTPicker control, a date can be added easily to the active cell with a userform.

[image]

The calendar form is displayed when it is double-clicked on any cell on the worksheet. Months are listed in the combobox control according to the user's system language starting from the month on the userform caption .

The ControlTipText value of the clicked button on the userform is added to the active cell as a date.

[Source (sample file can be downloaded here)](https://eksi30.com/add-date-to-cell-easily-with-excel-userform/)

Answer (score 0):

Using DTPicker (Date Picker) element in VBA Excel Module makes your work unsharable. That happened to me many times. I usually share my works with mates and they weren't able to proceed whenever they have been encountered with DTPicker missing library problems.

Installing Microsoft Common Control 2 SP6 and then Register its service is not an everyone's cup of tea. So, Instead of using DTPicker element, I have developed my own Date Picker which is more convenient, easy and applicable.

here's the link to the Form File.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bwxtkw03kytcv8v/Form%20Files.rar?dl=0

Steps to use this Form

1. Import it
2. Now, in your USERFORM, in Date area (textbox), execute my form file with double-click event.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2iY1.jpg)